# MSTests fail on build server after passing locally

Tags: msbuild, continuous-integration, mstest, gitlab, localdb

This is a bit odd for me, I've worked through several micro-services with unit tests and haven't experienced a problem like this.  The issue is that my unit tests pass locally but *some* fail on our build server.  The oddity about this is that if I single out a failing test in the build script it will pass.  If I run it with a test that was running before it I get the failure result.  If I remote into the test server and access the test result file and rerun all the tests, they will all pass.  So to me this says it has to do with my build environment - likely the "runner" context.  The specific error I get on failed tests is:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

Again, a test had ran and passed that was accessing the DB right before this failing test.  Additionally it should be noted that these tests are using stored procedures to access the data and also are using LINQ to SQL (.dbml).  I initially thought it had to do with the context not properly being disposed of but after several iterations of IDisposable implementation and peppering using statements throughout the data access code I think I have ruled that out.  I even went so far as to rip out the .dbml reference and new up an entity model (.edmx) but ended up getting the same results the end, after much simplification of the problem.  I can reproduce the issue with just 2 unit tests now, one will pass, one will fail.  When ran separately they both pass, when ran manually either locally or on the build server both will pass.

### **Dev Server**

We have our dev environment setup to be a remote server.  All devs use VS 2013 Ultimate.  All devs use a shared instance of localdb.  This seems to be working fine, I am able to develop and test against this environment.  All my tests pass here for the solution in question.  Then I push code upstream to the build server.

### **Build Server**

This is a windows 2012 server with GitLabs installed, every commit to our dev branches run build via the .gitlab-ci.yml build script.  For the most part this is just simple msbuild -> mstest calls, nothing too fancy.  This server also has its own shared instance of localdb running with matching schemas from the Dev environment.  Several other repositories have passing builds/unit tests utilizing this setup.  The connection strings for accessing data are all using integrated security, and the gitlab runner service account has full privs to the localdb.  The only thing I can identify as notably different about the solution in question is the heavy use of sprocs, however like I was saying some of these unit tests do pass and they are **all** using sprocs.  Like I also mentioned, after the build fails if I manually go in and access the test results file and manually invoke the tests on the build server they suddenly all pass.

So I'm not really sure what is going on here, has anyone experienced this sort of behavior before?  If so, how did you solve it?  I'd like to get these tests passing so my build can pass and move on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have got the unit tests to pass but it was a weird thing that I ended up doing to get them to pass and I'm not quite sure why this worked.  Even though the runners account had FULL "Server Role" privs on the localdb instance (all the boxes checked) I decided to throw up a hail marry and went through the process of "mapping" the user to the DB in question, setting his default schema to dbo and giving him full privs (all boxes checked).  After this operation...the tests pass.  So I'm clearly not understanding something about the way permissions are propagated in localdb, I was under the assumption that a server role of god-like would imply full privs to individual dbs but I guess not?  I'm no DBA, I'm actually going to chat with our DBA and see what he thinks.  Perhaps this has something to do with the sproc execution?  Maybe that requires special privs?  I do know in the passed that I've had to create special roles to execute sprocs, so they are a bit finicky.  Anyways, unit tests pass so I'm happy now!